# How can I keep a folder name from being changed by anyone who doesn't have administrator priviledges?

Tags: windows, group-policy

I need to make the files in a folder **and** the folder name itself unchangeable by users.  I've tried making the folder read only in it's properties but this only makes the files in the folder read only.  I tried the DOS attribute command on the folder but that didn't work.  I tried setting permissions in the security tab of the folder properties.  That didn't work.  Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have inherited access permissions which are giving write access to the users.

Try the following. Open the security tab, select the group of users who should only have read access, mark the checkbox for deny write.

Deny takes priority over other options.

Answer (score -1):

The only thing that you need to do is having this folder into a folder the users can't write in.

```
/path/users/cant/write/into                           dr-xr-xr-x
                        `-- WritingFolderForUsers     drwxrwxrwx
```

And that is. Nobody will be able to rename the "WritingFolderForUsers" but they will be able to create content inside.

You can find an example of this in the "/home" folder in linux which have all users homes and they can write into "his" folder ("/home/user") but he can't rename its folder.

Windows works in the same way, look at the "/Users/" path and you will find an example of this very same structure.